# Shizuo Heiwajima gets shot on which episode I can't find that clip

Tags: durarara

I know when the **Yellow Scarves** gets overtaken by the **Leader** of **Blue Squares** and one of the **Yellow Scarves** gang member shots **Shizuo** and blames **Masaomi** for that but i cant find that episode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scene is from episode 22. It begins around 21:20 and ends at about 21:55, at least on the Japanese bluray.

You probably haven't been able to find it on YouTube due to the content ID system; there is seemingly some background music or something during that scene that causes it to get instantly blocked.